# Xcode 15 Beta Issues - Error for aueryMetaDataSync & Unsupported action selector

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, swiftui, beta

I'm trying to use the 1st Beta of Xcode 15 with macOS Ventura 13.4. I've downloaded the link with Safari, unzipped, and then opened the iOS_17_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg and copied over the file "iOS 17.0.simruntime" to the requested spot:
//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/
There was a security flag when first opening Xcode, but I closed Xcode, opened Security preferences & fixed this, rebooting the Mac before re-opening Xcode again, just to be sure. The security issue goes away.
BUT when trying to run very basic code using a TextField (see image below), it does not work in the LivePreview and when run in the simulator, as soon as I click in the textfield, I see the info below (Metadata from Debug pane: copied & pasted)
`

Error for queryMetaDataSync: 2

Type: Error | Timestamp: 2023_06_07 10:22:41.3230-04:00 | Library: DataDeliveryServices | Subsystem: com.apple.DataDeliveryServices | Category: Query | TID: 0x3659
Unsupported action selector setShiftStatesNeededInDestination:autoShifted:shiftLocked:
Type: Error | Timestamp: 2023_06_07 10:22:41.4790-04:00 | Library: UIKitCore | Subsystem: com.apple.UIKit | Category: UIKeyboardImpl | TID: 0x3478
`

The code works fine on prior versions of Xcode. Does anyone have advice on how to fix this? Anyone else seeing this behavior? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: This likely belongs in feedback assistant rather than SO. What does Apple say about backwards compatibility? Bindable?

Comment: Same error with Xcode 14.3.1, so it's not about beta Xcode

Answer (score 1):

At least for me, I could not download either the 1st or 2nd Xcode beta to the Desktop & then decompress. I needed to keep it in the Downloads folder. After that there was no need to touch the iOS_17_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg, opening the Xcode_15_beta.xip took care of all of the installation & created the Xcode_beta app.
Also note that there are a lot of bugs in the Simulator, with the software Keyboard often not showing/toggling after command+K, or not accepting typing from the Mac keyboard. In the simulator app, selecting IO > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard, setting it off, then on again, should allow the Mac to begin typing to the simulator.

Comment: Sounds like it's a very long way off anything remotely useable. There's no indicator either that it won't work on MacOS 13.3.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just change the simulator, firstly this case happens when I'm using iPhone 14 pro simulator but after that, I change to iPhone 14 then the problem is solved. And finally I'm run on iPhone 14 Pro again and the problem didn't appear again.